# VBA website automation

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon All,

I have created some code that automatically logs me into my works website, however when trying to get the VBA to enter value into one of the search boxes I always recieve error 438: Object doesn't support this propery or method.

This is my code below please can you help:

```
Option Explicit

Const MyUserName As String = "username"
Const MyPassword As String = "password"

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

Dim objIE As Object


Sub LoginScript()

Dim Message, Title, Default
Dim MyValue As String
Dim currenttime As Date

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    If MsgBox("Do you want to search for a member?", vbYesNo, "Login") = 
vbNo Then
With objIE
.Visible = True
.Silent = True
.Navigate ("https://XXXXXXXXX.com/")
Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop
.Document.all.txtuserid.Value = MyUserName
.Document.all.txtpassword.Value = MyPassword
.Document.all.save_button.Click
Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop
End With
    Else

    Message = "Please enter clients CTC number"    ' Set prompt.
    Title = "Member Search"    ' Set title.
    ' Display message, title, and default value.
     MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title)

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate ("https://XXXXXXXXX.com/")
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop
    .Document.all.txtuserid.Value = MyUserName
    .Document.all.txtpassword.Value = MyPassword
    .Document.all.save_button.Click
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop
    currenttime = Now
    Do Until currenttime + TimeValue("00:00:10") <= Now
    Loop
    Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop
    .Document.getElementsById("txtClientRef").Value = MyValue <------ Errors Here
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using a different method to fill in the search field than your login credentials?  Which, by the way, is a very bad idea.

Comment: I tried the same method and this didnt work either. I am the only one with access the the file that contains the code and i have aldo password protected the file

Comment: http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/02/vba-ie-createevent-and-dispatchevent-to.html#focusTip  Helps to set the focus on the control you are manipulating.

Comment: I am still receiving error 424

Answer (score 2):

Id should be unique, and the syntax is `getElementById`, so try:

```
 .Document.getElementById("txtClientRef").Value
```

It is also a good idea to do `.Document.getElementById("txtClientRef").Focus` first.

If this then yields runtime error 424 it may be either that the object doesn't exist, as specified, or is not available at the time you attempt the assignment. For the latter to you can attempt to loop until not nothing with a specified timeout.

Comment: Beat me to it. Posting the:
.Document.getElementsById("txtClientRef").Value

Comment: This has now caused the error to change. I am now getting error 424. Object Required

Comment: Well that suggests it either doesn't exist or is not available at the time you attempt the assignment.

Comment: Is there a URL to share? And did you right click inspect on the element in the webpage?

Comment: unfortunately I can not share the URL as it is used by my work for all of our clients. I have inspected the page and the box I am trying to fill is under a Span class with the name "form_element varchar" then the ID of the box is "txtClientRef"

Comment: can you show that bit? Though by ID should work by itself. Have you tried pausing to ensure page is loaded and then attempting to select?

Comment: <span class="form_element varchar" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en"><input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" class="varchar" id="txtClientRef" name="txtClientRef" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en"></span>                                                                     
<input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" class="varchar" id="txtClientRef" name="txtClientRef" dir="ltr" lang="en" xml:lang="en">  When i inspect the page and select the correct box, this is what gets highlighted

Comment: Have you tried looping until element is visible? See example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378198/6241235