# Unable to set timeout option within my scraper to save it from infinite looping

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, timeout, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba using IE to initiate a search in a webpage in it's searchbox to populate the result according to the search by hitting the search button. The webpage loads it's `searchbox` few seconds later it is made to open. However, my below script can handle this barrier and perform the search in the right way.

Now, I've got a slightly different question which is: suppose I've defined a wrong `ID` name or There is no such `ID` in that webpage then the way I've written my script will loop forever. This is certainly a serious issue.

How can I modify my script putting some `timeout` option within the loop so that the scraper will wait sometime for the element to appear and if the element is not present within that time then it will break out of the loop and quit the browser. Thanks in advance.

Here is my script:

```
Sub GetItems()
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With New InternetExplorer
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://torrentz2.eu/"
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .Document

        With HTML
            Do     ''Wish to set timeout options within this loop to save it from infinite looping
                Set post = .getElementById("thesearchbox")
                DoEvents
            Loop While post Is Nothing

            post.innerText = "Udemy"

            .getElementById("thesearchbutton").Click
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, It is required to add `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to the reference library before executing the above script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
    With HTML
        Do     ''Wish to set timeout options within this loop to save it from infinite looping
            Set post = .getElementById("thesearchbox")
            DoEvents
        Loop While post Is Nothing

        post.innerText = "Udemy"

        .getElementById("thesearchbutton").Click
    End With
```

with

```
Dim dTime as Single ' as pointed out by @Mathieu Guindon in comments
'____________________________

dTime = Timer

With HTML
    Do     ''Wish to set timeout options within this loop to save it from infinite looping
        Set post = .getElementById("thesearchbox")
        If Timer - dTime > 60 Then Exit Do ' 60: num of seconds, equal 1 min
        DoEvents
    Loop While post Is Nothing

    post.innerText = "Udemy"

    .getElementById("thesearchbutton").Click
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Mistella for your epic solution. It is just perfect. Plus 1 in advance. One simple thing to know: `Dim dTime as what??` Gonna accept it soon. Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited to include. It's possible there's a better option than `Double`, but that's what I've always seen it as, in other code samples.

Comment: Solution accepted. I wish I could hit the upvote button several times.

Comment: @Topto caveat: don't run this code in the minute before midnight in your system's set time zone; `Timer - dTime` will start going negative in that edge case, since the `Timer` functions returns the number of seconds since midnight. FWIW `Timer` is `VBA.DateTime.Timer`, and returns a `Single`. Other code samples' authors didn't bother looking up the function in the object browser ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks, I edited my answer to make `dTime` a single. Learn something new everyday :)